# CP Content>Edit "edits" and Content>Edit>xxxxx "Publishes"

Tags: control-panel

I have a small but strange behaviour showing up in the CP following an upgrade of ee from 2.4 to 2.9.2.

When you navigate via the top menu bar to content>edit and hover over "edit" the link - it takes you to "CP Home>Edit" page as it should.

But when you navigate further in the drop down menu to any of the channels (Content>Edit>Homepage for example) the link that is shown is ../index.php?/cp/content_publish/entry_form&channel_id....

If you click on Content>edit>homepage you are delivered to an empty Publish screen for homepage channel (the breadcrumb shows: CP Home>Publish New Entry>Homepage)

Although I had quite a bit of fiddling to do to get all my modules and extensions upgraded and working following the big upgrade of ee, the actual ee upgrade seemed to go without a problem, so I'm a bit lost as to why I should be seeing this.

Site otherwise functional - its just very annoying!

Any ideas or help much appreciated. 
James.

Comment: Are you using any extensions which modify the menus or control panel appearance?

Comment: Bravo Derek - a very astute enquiry which resolved my issue! I disabled anything affecting how the CP could look... turns out it was the "BN Edit Menu" extension at fault. As soon as that was disabled the CP functionality returned to normal. Many thanks!